# Accessing maven binary from a node.js app using Heroku

Tags: node.js, maven, heroku

I have a node.js application that builds maven applications during the slug-compile phase (using a post-install script). Unfortunately the mvn binary isn't available, and all attempts at using different buildpacks have failed (tried multipack, regardless of order it wouldn't work). Is there any way to do this without writing my own buildpack?